# Compiler ignoring subsequent commands

Tags: c, pointers

I have the following C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char* ptr;
    printf("Enter the word: ");
    gets(ptr);
    printf("The input string is: ");
    puts(ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

It compiles and asks for the input, but after I enter the input, it takes a pause and exits. No further commands are executed or displayed. I am unable to understand the problem. Please help.

Comment: 1) `gets` is dangerous/deprecated in old standards and removed in the current one, instead use `fgets()`  2) You don't have room to store the string, switch from `char *ptr` to something like `char str[128]`

Comment: @DavidRanieri Why we don't have room for storing a string? I mean, the pointer can simply point to the first location of the memory where the string gets stored, so we need not worry, right?

Comment: To what memory do you expect `gets(ptr)` to be writing? Where does `ptr` point? And as @DavidRanieri mentioned: The `gets` function was actually removed in C11 so ... never use it.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I expect that when we input a string to the console and press enter, it goes somewhere in the memory and ptr pointer points to that location.

Comment: That _somewhere_ is up to you as a programmer to decide. It doesn't happen magically. Right now, it uses the uninitialized `ptr` so your program has undefined behavior. Try `char ptr[256]; fgets(ptr, 256, stdin);` instead.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I see. So, we have to allocate the memory dynamically till we encounter \n and need to put \0 by ourselves. Am I right?

Comment: That's one option - or if you can limit the input to a certain amount of characters, like 256, just preallocate an array like I showed above - and as shrey now shows in the answer below.

Comment: @Kumar there are functions that creates / reserves space for you, i.e. `strdup` , `getline`, but it is not the case for `gets` and `fgets`, they expect a buffer big enough to store the result, in the case of `fgets` there is a buffer overflow protection: the second parameter is the `sizeof` the buffer.

Comment: a function call like that `func(ptr)` (where `func` is any function) cannot change the value of `ptr`. If it was uninitialised before, then it cannot become magically initialised after. If it was `NULL`, it will remain `NULL`, etc.

Comment: You are using `ptr` without initilization. If your compiler did not warn you about that, you should turn up warning level. For GCC you can do this with options `-Wall -Wextra`.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char str[100] = "";
    printf("Enter the word: ");
    fgets(str, sizeof str, stdin);
    printf("The input string is: ");
    printf("%s", str);
    return 0;
}
```

Try to use `fgets()`. `gets()` is dangerous to use because `gets()` is inherently unsafe, because it copies all input from **STDIN** to the buffer without checking size. This allows the user to provide a string that is larger than the buffer size, resulting in an overflow condition.

`puts` is simpler than `printf` but be aware that the former automatically appends a newline. If that's not what you want, you can `fputs`your string to stdout or use `printf`.